# Python: If conditional statement not printing what I expect it to

Tags: python, conditional-statements

I have been working on this code:

```
print('Type any number or letter to start. ')
begin = input()
if begin != "Z" or 'z':
    print("Starting up!")
elif begin == "Z" or "z":
    print("Except Z")
```

When I run it, I expect it to be that when I type "Z" for the input, it prints the message "Except Z". Instead, it prints "Starting up!" which seems to be very counter-intuitive. Can anyone find where my problem is?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to phrase what you mean in Python.

```
print('Type any number or letter to start. ')
begin = input()
if begin == "z" or begin == "Z":
    print("Except Z")
else:
    print("Starting up!")
```

is the first;

```
print('Type any number or letter to start. ')
begin = input()
if begin in ("z", "Z"):
    print("Except Z")
else:
    print("Starting up!")
```

is another idiomatic way.

The problem in your original code, anyway, is that `or` has a lower precedence, so as far as Python is concerned, it ends up as

```
(or
   (begin != "Z")
   ("z")
)
```

and `"z"` is always truthy.

Comment: Ah, thank you so much. That helps.